# Format Text with leading apostrophe

Tags: formatting, phpexcel

Need to format the header row of my file to be formatted as that when you view the cell in the Excel spreadsheet it shows as HEADER but when you click that cell in the formula bar it shows 'HEADER.

I've tried seemingly just about everything with no luck. Whatever i try displays it in the cell as 'HEADER. However if I double click that cell in Excel it autoformats the way I want and strips the apostrophe out of the cell and leaves it in the formula bar.
And excel does that as well in a new cell where I type 'WHATEVER it will just display WHATEVER in the cell and still display 'WHATEVER in the formula bar.

How can I do this so it's already displayed that way when I create my Excel file with phpExcel?

This is how I'm inserting the values right now.

```
$objPHPExcel
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValueExplicit(
        $currentColumn.$currentRow, 
        $data, 
        PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING
    );
```

$data would just be a string preceded by an apostrophe.

Comment: Just as a general question, why?

Comment: client request...and that's my question as well but that's what they want. Thanks for the answer going to test your solution shortly.

Comment: I'd need to check what needed to be done for the Excel5 equivalent, and see if the other writers supported it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't actually a feature that PHPExcel supports (incredibly, nobody has ever asked for it before), though you could modify the code to support it by adding a quotePrefix attribute to the cell style (with appropriate getter and setter), and then modifying the writer to write a `quotePrefix="1"` attribute to the xf record when it writes the style to the styles.xml file (for Excel2007)

**EDIT**

Might need a bit of tweaking, but should be fairly straightforward

Classes/PHPExcel/Style.php

add a new attribute of $_quotePrefix (type Boolean, default false) and provide getter setter methods for it.

Classes/Reader/Excel2007.php

somewhere between lines 500 and 533, test for the quotePrefix xf attribute value; and add a call to $objStyle (defined in line 577) to call the quotePrefix setter if the xf attribute value was "1".

Classes/Writer/Excel2007/Style.php

Modify the xf writer (around line 399) to write a quotePrefix attribute with a value of "1" if the $pStyle quotePrefix property is true

Comment: Mark, Any idea which file(s) I would need to be editing? Poked around a bit and not sure exactly where I would need to add those. Thanks

Comment: Getting this warning when i try to add that attribute. 
PHP Warning:  XMLWriter::writeAttribute(): Invalid Attribute Name in ../phpexcel/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Style.php on line 409

Tried setting it with both 1 and true same result. 
$objWriter->writeAttribute('quotePrefix ', true );

And if I surpress Warnings and open the created file the quotePrefix is not there so guessing I need to add that as a valid phpExcel attribute somewhere?

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: Oops...just realized i had a space after quotePrefix so that was the issue. with the above comment

Comment: Hmmmm, yes... a space in the attribute name would be invalid: do you have it working now?

Comment: Kind of. One last issue. I had to hardcode the if loop in Style.php that does writeAttribute because it was never getting in here. 
if ($pStyle->getQuotePrefix() === true)

This is how I'm applying it. Does this look correct? 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->setQuotePrefix(true);

And if I dump $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getQuotePrefix() right after that it says it's true. But it's never getting into that if block.

Comment: I have $this->_quotePrefix = false in the contructor. And my function is simple. 
public function setQuotePrefix($pValue)
 {
  $this->_quotePrefix = $pValue;
 }
 When I dump $pStyle I can see _quotePrefix if false at least on the first call. And I'm setting it on every cell right now for testing.

Comment: Still can't seem to get that. In my loop where i'm applying it if i call getStyle() on that cell and getQuotePrefix it returns true. But in Style.php $pStyle->getQuotePrefix() is always false. 

Any thoughts?

Comment: Looking at it now: I'd forgotten adding it to the style hash - which I've now done - and adding a new style map, because it's the only style element defined at that level rather than in a subclass; but getting similar result to yourself. I may end up creating a new subclass, but I'll push the code to github once I've got it working

Comment: Pushed change for quotePrefix to the develop branch on github - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel